# is there a criterion for a two-generator subgroup of $PL(2,K)$ to be a cocompact lattice?

Tags: algebraic-groups, local-fields

In the case of the group $SO(n,1)$ there is a criterion known for whether or not two given elements of the group generate a cocompact lattice. Is any similar criterion known in the case of $PL(2,K)$ for $K$ a non-archimedean local field, or for some other $p$-adic group?

Comment: what is this criterion for $SO(n,1)$ please?

Comment: I second the question!

Comment: I do not believe there is a criterion for $SO(n,1)$. There is a couple of  semi-algorithms (for an arbitrary finite collection of elements of $SO(n,1)$). One of the two semi-algorithms is due to Troel Jorgensen. The second is a bit more complicated and is not in the literature; unlike Jorgensen's semi-algorithm, it applies to all real rank 1 noncompact simple Lie groups.

Comment: Yes, I apologise, I think I was mistaken. I was told that there was a criterion like this in Beardon's book "The Geometry of Discrete Groups" but I am having difficulty locating any result like that in the book.

Comment: I would like to know how to prove that if $\gamma$ is an element of a torsion-free cocompact lattice in $PL(2,K)$ for $K$ a non-archimedean local field then the eigenvalues of $\gamma$ are in $K$. Ihara appears to make this claim in his article "Discrete subgroups of $PL(2,k_{\mathcal{P}})$.

Comment: If this is what you want to know, that should be your question: how to prove that the element $\gamma$ has its eigenvalues in $K$? The proof is the same as for reals!